# Post Status With Upload Media using Twitter API (version 1.1) in Java

Tags: java, servlets, twitter, twitter4j

I want to know how to update my status with upload media on twitter using java. Currently my code work fine without including media upload script using **Twitter4J Library** [LINK](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html) but i could not understand how to upload media with my status using twitter api and itegrate it with my current Twitter4j code.[Twitter Upload Media API Reference](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update_with_media).

I googled for my solution and found link [Posting a Status Update with an Image (gitHub)](https://github.com/francisli/processing-http/wiki/Examples%3a-Twitter-API), but this reference is much complexed because it is basically using PApplet. and i want to do it with normal http post with no extend papplet class.

Any help / tutorial that shows Post Status With media(image) on JAVA ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
        String accesst = "ACCESS_TOKEN";
        String accessts = "TOKEN_SECRET";
        ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.setOAuthAccessToken(accesst);
        builder.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(accessts);
        builder.setOAuthConsumerKey("CLIENT_ID");
        builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret("CLIENT_SECRET");
        OAuthAuthorization auth = new OAuthAuthorization(builder.build());
        Twitter twitter_auth = new TwitterFactory().getInstance(auth);
        String screenName = twitter_auth.getScreenName();

        StatusUpdate status = new StatusUpdate("STATUS_TEXT");
        status.setMedia(new File("YOUR_FILE_PATH"));// BY SPECIFYING FILE PATH
        //status.setMedia("File name", new FileInputStream("")); // By InputStream
        Status updateStatus = twitter_auth.updateStatus(status);
        long id = updateStatus.getId(); // id of the status posted
```

For posting image from any url:

```
        String img_url = "http://www.qualitywallpapers.net/w/media/original/2013/02/23/Twitter-bird-logo-PNG.png";
        URL url1 = new URL(img_url);
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url1);
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(image, "image/png", os);
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());
        status.setMedia("hello", is);// By Stream
```

Comment: it couldn't resolve type StatusUpdate. ? any help regarding this?

Comment: which version of twitter4j are you using?

Comment: twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar, i think it updated jar file on twitter4j

Comment: 3.0.3 is also fine, check does it have StatusUpdate class??

Comment: include import twitter4j.StatusUpdate; in your imports, and check if its there?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39624/discussion-between-waqas-ahmed-and-jhanvi)

Comment: Using Twitter4j 4.0.4, this code didn't work until I changed the image type in ImageIO.write to "png" instead of "image/png".  (Was getting error #189 from Twitter API)

Answer (score 1):

I SOLVED my problem by using Twitter4j 3.0.4 & Twitter4j 3.0.4 - media library. you can download it by [click here](http://twitter4j.org/archive/twitter4j-3.0.4.zip)

### **Tweet status Posting With Image on TWITTER Working Code.**

```
import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;
import twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization;
import twitter4j.auth.RequestToken;
import twitter4j.User;

import twitter4j.conf.Configuration;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;
import twitter4j.media.ImageUpload;
import twitter4j.media.ImageUploadFactory;
import twitter4j.media.MediaProvider;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public final class PostWithImage {


    /**
     * Developer : Waqas Ghouri
     * Email     : waqas_ghouri89@hotmail.com
     * @param args message
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws TwitterException {

        String UserAccessToken = null;
        String UserAccessSecret = null;

        try {

            Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();


             //Set Your Application Consumer Key & Consumer Key Secret
             twitter.setOAuthConsumer("xxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

            try {
                // get request token.
                // this will throw IllegalStateException if access token is already available
                RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
                System.out.println("Got request token.");
                System.out.println("Request token: " + requestToken.getToken());
                System.out.println("Request token secret: " + requestToken.getTokenSecret());


                AccessToken accessToken = null;


                // to check this example set you callback URL to empty. If your application 
                // callback URL is defined then URL generated by below code should be redirected
                // to callback URL, so when we set callback URL to empty it shows PIN CODE to access OAUTH

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                while (null == accessToken) {
                    System.out.println("Open the following URL and grant access to your account:");
                    System.out.println(requestToken.getAuthorizationURL());
                    System.out.print("Enter the PIN(if available) and hit enter after you granted access.[PIN]:");
                    String pin = br.readLine();
                    try {
                        if (pin.length() > 0) {
                            accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, pin);
                        } else {
                            accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken);
                        }
                    } catch (TwitterException te) {
                        if (401 == te.getStatusCode()) {
                            System.out.println("Unable to get the access token.");
                        } else {
                            te.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Got access token.");
                UserAccessToken = accessToken.getToken();
                UserAccessSecret = accessToken.getTokenSecret();
                System.out.println("Access token: " + UserAccessToken);
                System.out.println("Access token secret: " + UserAccessSecret);


            } catch (IllegalStateException ie) {
                // access token is already available, or consumer key/secret is not set.
                if (!twitter.getAuthorization().isEnabled()) {
                    System.out.println("OAuth consumer key/secret is not set.");
                    System.exit(-1);
                }
            }

            //Fetching User Information
            //User Information from twitter.
            System.out.println("Connecting.... ");
            System.out.println("Twitter Connected To : ");

            User user = twitter.showUser(twitter.getId());
            System.out.print(user.getScreenName());
            if (user.getStatus() != null) {
                System.out.println("@" + user.getScreenName() + " - " + user.getStatus().getText());
            } else {
                // the user is protected
                System.out.println("@" + user.getScreenName());
            }


            // If you want simple post on status uncomment below code

            //System.out.println("Trying to simple post");      
            //Status status = twitter.updateStatus("Normal Post on Twitter Statsus");


            // Below code post with image and message           
            System.out.println("Now Try to upload Image");


            // Specify the image path in you system ( windows / unix / mac what ever)
            // ex(windows) : C:\imagepost.png
                    // ex(linux)   : /home/waqas/imagepost.png  
            String ImagePath = null;
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            while (null == ImagePath) {
                System.out.println("Please Type Image Path: ");
                String path = br.readLine();
                if (path.length() > 0) {
                    ImagePath = path;
                } else {
                    path = "";
                    System.exit(-1);
                }
            }


            // type your message(status)
            String Message = null;
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            while (null == Message) {
                System.out.println("Please type your message: ");
                String msg = br.readLine();
                if (msg.length() > 0) {
                    Message = msg;
                } else {
                    Message = "";
                    System.exit(-1);
                }
            }


             try {

                    Configuration conf = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                        .setOAuthConsumerKey("xxxxxx(OAuth Consumer Key)xxxxxx")
                                        .setOAuthConsumerSecret("xxxxxxxxxx(OAuth Consumer Secret)xxxxxxxx")
                                        .setOAuthAccessToken(UserAccessToken)
                                        .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(UserAccessSecret).build();


                    OAuthAuthorization auth = new OAuthAuthorization(conf);
                    ImageUpload upload = new ImageUploadFactory(conf).getInstance(auth);

                    String url;
                    if (ImagePath.length()>0) {
                        url = upload.upload(new File(ImagePath), Message);
                    } else {
                        url = upload.upload(Message,null);
                    }
                    System.out.println("Successfully uploaded image to Twitpic at " + url);
                    System.exit(0);
                } catch (TwitterException te) {
                    te.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("Failed to upload the image: " + te.getMessage());
                    System.exit(-1);
                }

            System.exit(0);


        } catch (TwitterException te) {
            //te.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Failed to get timeline: " + te.getMessage());
            System.exit(-1);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Failed to read the system input.");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }

}
```